# Blichmann QuickCarb and Bottling

Tags: bottling, carbonation, co2, force-carbonation, over-carbonation

I used this Quickcarb to carbonate my beer, but when bottled (with a BeerGun) I get too much foam in the bottle and almost no beer, after finally filling the bottle I tap it. And when I try my beer it does not have almost gas or sometimes nothing ...... do you have any advice that can help me with this? I would greatly appreciate it :).

Comment: After using the quick carb can you get a decent pour from the keg without foam?  Can you dispense to a glass fine?

Answer (score 1):

It's either over carbed or the beergun line needs tuned for the pressure.

I'm not a fan off applying increased pressure to carbonate quickly. When doing this you throw out all the math tables that have been established for proper carbonation,and are left guessing your final co2 volumes.

Carbonate and Serve your beer at the pressure the style calls for. Usually 12-13 psi at 38°F for most styles.

Then tune your beergun line. Get it to pour about as slow as you can stand it, I have mine set to pour about 3/4 oz a second so a 12oz is about a 20 second fill. I don't bottle much obviously, only for comps, gifts, etc. But anything faster, needs counter pressure imo to preserve the co2 volumes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are bottling beer that is already carbonated, ideally you want a counter-pressure filler. The filler pressurizes the bottle, keeps it sealed, and then you activate the filler. I don't know if the Blichmann rig does that.

One thing you can do is make sure your beer is as cold as possible. The colder the beer is, the better the CO2 will remain in solution.